# Open Map Activity from GCM Push Notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, google-cloud-messaging, android-location

I am trying to open a specific activity called 'MapActivity' where I want to load my current position on a map and get nearby places. I got that working and also got GCM working to send push notifications to my device (Android 4.3). The only problem left is opening that activity I wanted, everytime I click on the message it will end up on error.

Here is the activity I want to load:

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog, wDialog;
    //private static String dataUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-7.288804,%20112.814649&radius=5000&types=hospital&key=AIzaSyDuc4ab9iT7VPSZMCdKI416yQOeLprV5ME";

    private String API_KEY = "###MYAPIKEY###";
    private String PLACES_TYPE = "hospital";
    private String RADIUS = "5000";
    private static final int MAX_PLACES = 20;

    private static final String TAG_RESULTS = "results";
    private static final String TAG_GEOMETRY = "geometry";
    private static final String TAG_LOCATION = "location";
    private static final String TAG_LAT = "lat";
    private static final String TAG_LNG = "lng";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_VICINITY = "vicinity";

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected android.location.LocationListener locationListener;
    protected Context context;

    JSONArray tagResults = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> hospitalList;
    protected double currLat, currLng;
    Location currLocation;
    LatLng currLatLng;
    private boolean alreadySet = false;

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
        Log.d("Latitude", "disable");
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
        Log.d("Latitude","enable");
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
        Log.d("Latitude", "status");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        hospitalList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (android.location.LocationListener) this);



        new GetPlaces().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(alreadySet == false) {
            alreadySet = true;
            currLat = location.getLatitude();
            currLng = location.getLongitude();
            currLocation = new Location("Current Location");
            currLocation.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
            currLocation.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
            currLatLng = new LatLng(currLocation.getLatitude(),currLocation.getLongitude());
        }
    }



    private class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MapActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            while ( currLocation == null ) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            String api_address = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?";
            String api_lat = Double.toString(currLocation.getLatitude());
            String api_lng = Double.toString(currLocation.getLongitude());
            String param_location = "location=" + api_lat + "," + api_lng;
            String param_radius = "&radius=5000";
            String param_types = "&types=hospital";
            String param_key = "&key=AIzaSyDuc4ab9iT7VPSZMCdKI416yQOeLprV5ME";

            String apiURL = api_address + param_location + param_radius + param_types + param_key;

            ServiceHandler serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler();
            String jsonResponse = serviceHandler.makeServiceCall(apiURL,ServiceHandler.GET);
            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonResponse);
            if(jsonResponse!=null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
                    tagResults = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
                    for(int i=0; i<tagResults.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject resultObj = tagResults.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = resultObj.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = resultObj.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String vicinity = resultObj.getString(TAG_VICINITY);
                        JSONObject geometryObj = resultObj.getJSONObject(TAG_GEOMETRY);
                        JSONObject locationObj = geometryObj.getJSONObject(TAG_LOCATION);
                        String lat = locationObj.getString(TAG_LAT);
                        String lng = locationObj.getString(TAG_LNG);
                        HashMap<String, String> hospital = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        hospital.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        hospital.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        hospital.put(TAG_VICINITY, vicinity);
                        hospital.put(TAG_LAT, lat);
                        hospital.put(TAG_LNG, lng);
                        hospitalList.add(hospital);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
            if (mMap == null) {
                mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                        .getMap();
                if (mMap != null) {
                    for(int i=0; i<MAX_PLACES; i++)
                    {
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(currLatLng)
                                        .title("You are here now.")
                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                        );
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currLatLng, 14));
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(hospitalList.get(i).get(TAG_LAT)), Float.parseFloat(hospitalList.get(i).get(TAG_LNG))))
                                        .title(hospitalList.get(i).get(TAG_NAME))
                                        .snippet(hospitalList.get(i).get(TAG_VICINITY))
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the function where I use to send the notification on MyGCMListernerService.java

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param from SenderID of the sender.
     * @param data Data bundle containing message data as key/value pairs.
     *             For Set of keys use data.keySet().
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.d(TAG, "DATA: " + data);
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

        /**
         * Production applications would usually process the message here.
         * Eg: - Syncing with server.
         *     - Store message in local database.
         *     - Update UI.
         */

        /**
         * In some cases it may be useful to show a notification indicating to the user
         * that a message was received.
         */
        sendNotification(message);
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received GCM message.
     *
     * @param message GCM message received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent, 0);
        Log.i(TAG, "GCM Message: " + message);
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("GCM Message")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

I tried to set the Intent like this but it didn't work, it's showing like it was opening the activity tho, but then it says the app is closed.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MapActivity.class);
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0)
```

Would there be anyone willing to help point what's wrong in my code and what should I do to fix it? Thank you so much.

************************ EDIT *************************

I tried to open an empty activity and it worked.. I wonder if there's something wrong with my Map Activity? If it is used on a stand-alone app, it worked perfectly though.

I tried to make a new blank activity again, and paste all of my MapActivity code inside it and now I'm getting an error like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart/gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.MainActivity2Activity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.MainActivity2Activity cannot be cast to android.location.LocationListener
```

And it points out to this line

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (android.location.LocationListener) this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapActivity is extend by Fragment Activity and inside this you are opening Map i.e also opening inside a fragment so you cannot make a call to map directly with help of intent.
you can do this like as:
((MyFragmentActivity) getActivity()).replaceFragments();
and then inside fragment activity replace that fragment.

Comment: do I put this on PendingIntent ?

Comment: yes ,you can make a call to fragment from pending intent but replace funtionality to be handle from fragment activity

Comment: I'm still confused with this. Do I have to create a new activity with Fragment? Which resulted in 2 : MapActivity and MapActivityFragment and then put all the functionality in the MapActivityFragment? And then on the PendingIntent do like this? `PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.((MapActivityFragment)getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0)).replaceFragments();`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I finally figured out myself by making a new Blank Activity and putting all the Map code there and adding `implements android.location.LocationListener` would load the Map and changed nothing from the Intent and PendingIntent part. So I would say this problem as solved! Thanks